# Get my PKG Installer To Prompt and Store Admin User/Pass

Tags: macos, install, password, keychain, pkg

On Mac OSX, the third-party command line tool I have needs to run as super user unfortunately. I'm building a front-end GUI for it. My Qt/C++ application is using `QProcess` to shell out to Bash and run this command via `echo "{PASS}" sudo -l "{USER}" -S {COMMAND}`. I'm successful with that -- just as long as I have the Apple ID user/pass.

Is there a way my PKG installer can graphically prompt for Apple ID user/pass? Second, how would you recommend I store this securely?

Comment: You could possibly add a postinstall/preinstall action asking for the username and password.

Comment: I can use `echo "{PASSWORD}" | sudo -l "{USERNAME}" -S {COMMAND}`, but the problem is how to graphically prompt for that during the setup wizard of the PKG installation process?

Comment: you may be able to add a script which executes an app to get the user's password: [(here's a helpful link on pkg scripts)](http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html?m=1)

Comment: @IronCraftMan I may have found the answer. Can you confirm? When I read [some documentation about Apple's PackageManager tool](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html), when I scroll down in that, I think it says that if I choose the Admin Authorization flag on the installer, then all Bash scripts that run from that will run as root and will not require `sudo` authorization.

Comment: the should run as root, as all installer pkgs require an admin authorization.

Comment: @IronCraftMan I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you are stating in that sentence. "The should"? What should?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to say the package should run as root. It seems as if you solved your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this documentation...

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/Package_Settings_Customization.html#6

...it states that Apple PackageManager files (.PKG) files have an option to run with Administrator privileges. It specifically states:

> If you install anything in /Applications or /Library, this option
>   should be enabled.

Also, in this documentation...

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html

...it states that Bash scripts that you run will run under Administrator privileges (root) and therefore will not require `sudo` authentication to do powerful tasks.